# For how many $n < N$ is $d(n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factoring, integers

I was researching about integer partitions and came across the equation $d(n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Here, $d(n)$ is the number of factors of $n$ and $p$ is a fixed prime. How many solutions does this have when $n<N$? I thought this might be solvable if I factor $n$, but couldn't solve it.

All I got was that when $p=2$, this is $N-\sqrt{N}$ (a number has an odd number of factors exactly when it's a perfect square).

How should I go from here?

Also, is there a solution to the same problem but with $\sigma(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although **this is not a complete answer**, it might be useful to consider as a technique.

[First of all](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html), if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$ (prime factorisation of $n$), then $d(n)=(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)...(\alpha_k+1)$, [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)
$$d(n)\equiv 0 \pmod{p} \iff \exists \alpha_i, i\in \{1,..,k\}: p \mid \alpha_i+1 \tag{1}$$

---

**Proposition 1**. There are no solutions for $N<2^{p-1}$.

From $(1)$ we have $\alpha_i=p\cdot t -1$ and because $\alpha_i \geq 1$ then $t \geq 1$ or $\alpha_i \geq p-1$ and $n\geq p_i^{\alpha_i}\geq 2^{p-1}$. As a result, $N\geq 2^{p-1}$, otherwise - there are no solutions.

---

Now, with more details:

- $\color{red}{2}^{p-1}\times 1, 2^{p-1}\times 3, 2^{p-1}\times 5, 2^{p-1}\times 7, 2^{p-1}\times 9, ..., 2^{p-1}\times n_2 < N$ or
  $$1<3<5<7<9<...<n_2<\frac{N}{2^{p-1}}$$
  which are all the odd numbers $<\frac{N}{2^{p-1}}$, which is $\color{blue}{\approx\frac{N}{2^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{2\cdot2^{p-1}}}$.
- and so on for $2^{p\cdot t-1}=\color{red}{2^{p(t-1)}}\times 2^{p-1}$ to have $\color{blue}{\approx\frac{N}{2^{p(t-1)}\cdot 2^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{2\cdot 2^{p(t-1)}\cdot 2^{p-1}}}$
- $\color{red}{3}^{p-1}\times 1, 3^{p-1}\times 2, 3^{p-1}\times 4, 3^{p-1}\times 5, 3^{p-1}\times 7, ..., 3^{p-1}\times n_3 < N$ or 
  $$1<2<4<5<7<8<...<n_3<\frac{N}{3^{p-1}}$$
  or all the positive integers $<\frac{N}{3^{p-1}}$ not divisible by $3$, $\color{blue}{\approx \frac{N}{3^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{3\cdot3^{p-1}}}$
- and so on for $3^{p\cdot t-1}=\color{red}{3^{p(t-1)}}\times 3^{p-1}$ to have $\color{blue}{\approx\frac{N}{3^{p(t-1)}\cdot 3^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{3\cdot 3^{p(t-1)}\cdot 3^{p-1}}}$
- $\color{red}{5}^{p-1}\times 1, 5^{p-1}\times 2, 5^{p-1}\times 3, 5^{p-1}\times 4, 5^{p-1}\times 6, ..., 5^{p-1}\times n_5 < N$ or 
  $$1<2<3<4<6<7<8<9<11<...<n_5<\frac{N}{5^{p-1}}$$
  or all the positive integers $<\frac{N}{5^{p-1}}$ not divisible by $5$, $\color{blue}{\approx \frac{N}{5^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{5\cdot5^{p-1}}}$
- and so on for $5^{p\cdot t-1}=\color{red}{5^{p(t-1)}}\times 5^{p-1}$ to have $\color{blue}{\approx\frac{N}{5^{p(t-1)}\cdot 5^{p-1}}-\frac{N}{5\cdot 5^{p(t-1)}\cdot 5^{p-1}}}$
- and so on for $\color{red}{7}, \color{red}{11}, \color{red}{13}, ...$ i.e. primes.

This starts nicely to shape into something like

$$\sum\limits_{q-\text{prime}} \left( \sum\limits_{t=1} \left \lfloor \frac{(q-1)N}{q^{t\cdot p}} \right \rfloor \right) \tag{2}$$
**But, there is a problem.** For instance in the sequence for $\color{red}{2}$ we have $2^{p-1}\times 9$ and the sequence for $\color{red}{3}$ we have $3^{p-1}\times 4$. Depending on $N$, the sequence for $\color{red}{2}$ may contain $2^{p-1}\times 3^{p-1}$ and the sequence for $\color{red}{3}$ we have $3^{p-1}\times 2^{p-1}$. So we can have overlaps, leading to applying [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) which complicates the things. At least, the number of solutions should not exceed $(2)$.

Comment: Does this work with $\sigma (n)$ also?

Comment: $\sigma(n)$, also [knows as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Formulas_at_prime_powers) $\sigma_1(n)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}\frac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$, is a different function.

Comment: In that case, $\exists \alpha_i; p \mid \frac{q^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{q-1}$.

Comment: Yes, Euclid's lemma always holds ... also replace $q$ with $p_i$ (or $q_i$ to avoid confusing it with $p$).

Comment: But since we do not no whether $p$ and $p_i$ are coprime, it is hard to get a equation for $\alpha_i$

Comment: Well, since $p$ and $p_i$ are both primes, then either $p=p_i$ or $\gcd(p,p_i)=1$ (coprimes). You can rule out the 1st case easily since $\frac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}=p_i^{\alpha_i}+p_i^{\alpha_i-1}+...+p_i+1$ so if $p=p_i  \Rightarrow p \mid 1$ - which is a contradiction. So $\gcd(p,p_i)=1$.

Comment: I meant $p_i-1$ and $p$.

Comment: I see ... in any case, you are right, getting a useful expression for $\alpha_i$ is becoming indeed hard.

Comment: Also, isn't the number of numbers not divisible by $3$ under $N/3^{p-1}$: $2/3 \times N/3^{p-1}$?

Comment: So the sum should be $\sum_{q-prime} [\frac{q-1}{q^p} N]$?

Comment: Oh, yes ... good catch, I will update the answer. I should stop doing maths after 23:00 :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79780/discussion-between-kenta-s-and-rtybase).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is easy. The integers $n$ with $d(n)\equiv0\bmod3$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A059269. It is mentioned there that Charles R Greathouse has conjectured that the $n$th term in the sequence is asymptotic to $kn$, where $$k = \left(1 - \prod_p\left(1 - {p-1\over p^{3k}}\right)\right)^{-1} = 3.743455\dots$$

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: Is this not proven yet?

Comment: Sorry, all I know is what's at the OEIS page.